# Weird looking Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have never seen a JavaScript loop such as this **`for( ; i-- ; )`**, used in the code:

```
uid: function (len) {
    var str = '';
    var src = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var src_len = src.length;
    var i = len;

    for (; i--;) {
        str += src.charAt(this.ran_no(0, src_len - 1));
    }

    return str;
}
```

I understand the behavior, but I would like it if somebody could share some insights about this type of for loop.

Comment: It's exactly the same as `while(i--)`

Comment: `0` is falsy in JavaScript and all expressions in for loop are optional, so even `for (;;) ` is valid.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that in C, this kind of for loop isn't so unusual, and especially "for(;;)" is a well known idiom that can be read as "forever". (In fact, I believe this used to be very common. Not sure if this is still true.) But in JavaScript this style lacks clarity because it is not common. Therefore it should in general be avoided in code that other people might want to read. Unless you are sure it will only be read by C programmers.

Comment: I don't think a loop like this should ever be used.  for(;i--;) is equivalent to while(i--) and the latter makes it more apparent what's going on.  When faced with two ways of expressing something you should almost always take the clearer one--and in this case I would if anything expect the while loop to be faster also.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel While I agree with your assessment about choosing the most readable style, optimizing `for()` versus `while()` for speed is entering into Mordor and should be avoided almost always. That being said, relevant: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/performanceemptyloops.htm

Comment: @L0j1k I'm not saying it as an optimization, I'm saying there shouldn't be a hit from using the clearer form, thus there's no reason not to use it.

Comment: It's like the ["goes to" operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028) in `while (i --> 0) ...`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a syntax of the [`for-loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) construction:

> for ([*initialization*]; [*condition*]; [*final-expression*])
>        *statement*

In your case `for (; i--;) {`:

- no variables are initialized, because `var i = len;` inintialized earlier, so it's not needed.
- condition part will be truthy until `i` becomes `0` then loop will terminate. `i--` is executed on before each iteration, and due to `--` operator it will eventually become `0`, so it's falsy, and loop will stop.
- since `i` is decremented in condition part of the loop, `final-expression` is not needed too. Another way to put it: since `i` is not used inside the loop, it does not matter whether we decrement it before each loop iteration or after each loop iteration.

That being said, it's better to avoid writing loops like above, as it's pretty confusing and hard to read. Prefer traditional for-loops notation.

Comment: That being said, this style of looping is really bad because its so unclear. Just stick with the normal `for` loops.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Absolutely. I added a remark to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

From [MDN - for - Optional for expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Example.3A_Optional_for_expressions):

> All three expressions in the head of the for loop are optional.

You don't have to specify all three expressions in `for` loops. For example, `for (;;)` is a common wa of writing infinite loop.

In your case, `while(i--)` would have done the same, there is no good reason to write `for (; i--;)`.

I'd also note that `for(var i=len;i>=0;i--)` is more robust - it protects you from the case `len` is negative.

Comment: But it's worth noting that `for (; i--;)` is not the same as `for(;i!=0; i--)` because in the former case the `i--` is executed the first time you enter the loop whereas in the latter the `i--` is only executed at the end of each iteration.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth - I'm not sure what you mean, I never mentioned `for(;i!=0; i--)`. Good point though - if the code used `i`, that would make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

This could be rewritten to

```
uid: function (len) {
    var str = '';
    var src = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var src_len = src.length;
    var i = len;

    while (i >= 0) {
        str += src.charAt(this.ran_no(0, src_len - 1));
        i = i - 1;
    }

    return str;
}
```

> The for statement creates a loop that consists of three optional
>   expressions.

Javascript consider `0 == false` that's why in the case you presented the loop will run until the `i` variable became zero. It will loop as many times as the `src` string size.

Note: `i--` uses the variable value then decrements it. Take a look at the following situation:

```
for(;i--;) { // i = length in the condition
     // i === length - 1 here. It will not overflow the array
}

for(;i--;) { // i = 1
     // i === 0 here. It will be the last loop
}

for(;i--;) { // i == 0 == false
     // Not executed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong.

```
for(`INIT`;`TEST`;`ACTION`)
{
     `WORK`;
}
```

The `INIT` (initialization) can be done outside the loop.

```
var i=0;
for(;i<=100;i++)
//do something
```

The `TEST` part yield a result that is either `true` or `false`. Now in this case value of `i` is tested. Until it becomes zero this works.

The `ACTION` part is generally used to change the loop variable. But you can leave it also or probably add it to the `TEST` section like it is done here.

Look this examples are going to clear your idea

```
var i=0;
for( i++; i++; i+=j); //No body

var i=0;
for(;;); //an infinite loop

var i;
for(i=-4;i;i++);//
```

Even sometimes `WORK` is placed in `ACTION`.

Example:

### factorial of x

```
 for(var i=1,ans=1;i<=x;ans=ans*(i++));
```

---

```
Which can be written this way also-


 var ans=1;
for(var i=1;i<=x;i++)
   ans=ans*i;
```

**NOTE**: You can write whichever way you want. It doesn't matter as long as you have written the code properly. Get used to this kind of form you will see them a lot.

Though, it is better to write sometimes in compact form , but remember you should keep the **readability**.

Answer (score 1):

That's just for loop. Before the first semicolon the variable used in the loop is usually declared. But in this case the variable, the variable used in the loop is declared earlier:

```
var i = len;
   ^^^
for (; i--;) {...
```

So there is no need to redeclare.

After the first semicolon, there is a condition for the loop to run (i.e. `i<6`, `i>3`, etc). If condition returns `false`, or `0`, the loop is exited. In this case, the loop will be broken out when `i` is `0`. It happens eventually, because `--` after `i` decrements it, and therefore there is no need for the expression, which is the place after the second semicolon is reserved for.

Comment: The condition is there. Because it doesn't look like a condition that doesn't mean it's not a condition.

Comment: @DJD No condition there. What do you mean?

Comment: `i--` _returns_  the value of `i` and then decrements its value. At the time `i` is `0` the `i--` returns `0`  which is _falsy_ and as of that the condition will be evaluated to _false_. ( `for(;i--;)` is equal to `while(i--)` )

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the for loop has already been defined, so the initial comma is there to delimit it's place in the parameter list.

Comment: I used this kind of thing when I had another similar for loop after this where I was using i again but reset it to zero. Just some small optimization,

Comment: This isn't a very full answer as it doesn't address all the points of the question

Comment: I see that all the points of the question have now been addressed. But I can add that the scope of the i is now outside of the loop, so the value can be used if you break out of the loop prematurely after say finding some solution to a search of an array. Inside of the loop, the i is only locally accessible.